# How to persuade Doxygen to document two C structures that have the same name?

Tags: c, doxygen

The structures are being chosen to be compiled using different compiler flags (because in C you cannot have two different structures with the same name)
but I need both of them to be shown in Doxygen documentation. Currently, it looks like Doxygen only picks one of them to be shown in the doxy files?
How can we solve this? Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Did you try  something with the diferet DEFINE / PREPROCESSING switches in the doxygen configuration file (should behave a bit in the same way as the compiler switches).

Comment: yes I tried that, but this is not good for me because it only picks one of the definition of the structure and I want to represent both in the doxy file